# Try to web scrape with Gemini

Tags: web-scraping, google-gemini

I decided to use the Gemini API because of a job I got. Although everything is going very well, I have a problem. When I ask Gemini AI a question about today's news, it constantly assumes that we are in 2023 and brings the data of the old site in a way I don't know how it does it. Of course, I don't want to pull news from a website, I know there are easier ways to do this, but when I want to ask for any current information, phones, cars, etc. always come back to me with old information. Is there any way to fix this?
Do you have a suggestion like if I forward the current version of the website to him, can he give me the answers?[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtjFZ.png)
Note: Today's date is March 21, 2024

Try to web scrape with Gemini but scraped old version of website everytime